# react npm production Build issue

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, npm-install

Unable to create execute  `npm run build` when I set NODE_ENV to production

export NODE_ENV = production

then run npm install, it's not installing dev dependencies   so

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in

```
  entry: ['@babel/polyfill', path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/index.js')],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: /src\/js\/libs/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]',
        },
      }
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
export NODE_ENV=production
```

instead of

```
export NODE_ENV = production
```

Answer (score 0):

`NODE_ENV=production` will prevent development dependencies from being installed. If you need the development dependencies installed but also want/need `NODE_ENV=production` for other reasons, you can temporarily override the value of the environment variable for the `npm install` command only:

```
NODE_ENV=development npm install
```

Or you can use a command line flag to indicate that you want the development dependencies installed:

```
npm install --production=false
```